# Navigate to another screen - 'navigation.navigate' is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to navigate from Screen1 to Screen2. Screen1 is being rendered in my Home screen. So far I have tried using `this.props.navigation.navigate` as well as what you see currently implemented.

I have created a [snack expo here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/navigate-from-function-to-component) that recreates the exact error as well as posted some code below.

Thank you for any insight at all, I appreciate it more than you know.

EDIT:: this needs to be ran on IOS and I am using `react-native-navigation`

App.js

```
 /*passing props to home is from my overall project, I left it in incase it impacted the answer*/ 
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" options={{ headerShown: false }}>
        {(props) => (
          <Home {...props}/>
        )}
      </Stack.Screen>
       <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen1"
        component={Screen1}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen2"
        component={Screen2}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
}


export default function App() {

  return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <MyTabs/>
</NavigationContainer>
);
```

Screen1

```
export default class Screen1 extends React.Component {
  renderList = (props, navigation) => {
    return List.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <View
        key={List.name}
          style={{
            width: windowWidth,
            height: scale(100),
            paddingLeft: scale(10)
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2')}
            activeOpacity={0.7}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{item.name}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
  return (
      <View style={{top: scale(50)}}>

          <ScrollView style={{ height: windowHeight }}>
            <this.renderList />
          </ScrollView>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is on IOS, apologies for not mentioning that

Comment: Only answers need an "edit: ..." (because a _lot_ of time can pass), questions just get more details worked in to make sure the question makes sense start to finish. Whoever looks at it after your edit should see a normal post =)

Comment: Is it working well on android?

Comment: same error on android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use of hook `useNavigation`.

**Home.js**

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View>
      <Screen1 navigation={navigation} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

**Screen1.js**

```
export default class Screen2 extends React.Component {

  renderList = (props) => {
    return List.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <View
          key={List.name}
          style={{
            width: windowWidth,
            height: scale(100),
            paddingLeft: scale(10),
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            props.navigation.navigate('Screen2')
          }} activeOpacity={0.7}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{item.name}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

render() {
  const props= this.props;
  return (
    <View style={{ top: scale(50) }}>
      <ScrollView style={{ height: windowHeight }}>
         { this.renderList (props) }
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
}
```

[snack expo working code](https://snack.expo.dev/@nilesh.nvs/navigate-from-function-to-component)

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if Screen1 is a function, I need it to be a React component like it is in my snack example.

Comment: @JustinPriede i can get it work with class component as well. Please give me some time.

Comment: No worries! No rush.

Comment: @JustinPriede Its done. try the same link..

Answer (score 0):

In Screen 1

```
renderList = (props) => {
return List.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <View
    key={List.name}
      style={{
        width: windowWidth,
        height: scale(100),
        paddingLeft: scale(10)
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2')}
        activeOpacity={0.7}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>{item.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
});
```

in Home

```
const Home = (props) => {


return (
<View>
    <Screen1 {...props}/>
</View>

);
```

}

And in App

```
<Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" options={{ headerShown: false }} component={Home}/>

   <Tab.Screen
    name="Screen1"
    component={Screen1}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />

  <Tab.Screen
    name="Screen2"
    component={Screen2}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />
```

</Tab.Navigator>

And for me working perfectly (I take some capture but I'm not authorized yet, new user...)

Say me

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `navigation props` to **Screen1**. You can just pass navigation props to Screen1 like below code or it is better to make **Screen1** as **Initial Route** instead of calling it as a component in **Home screen**.

**Good method** : Update following area in **App.js** like below

```
.... 
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Screen1"> // made Screen1 as initial route
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen1"
        component={Screen1}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Screen2"
        component={Screen2}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
  </Stack.Navigator> 
....
```

**Method 2** : If you want Home Screen as Initial Route, then update following area in **Home.js** like below

```
....
const Home = (props) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Screen1 navigation={props.navigation}/> // navigation props passed to Screen1 component
      </View>
    );
}
....
```